# NSURLSession POST method not getting response properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post, nsurlsession

I am sending POST request using NSURLSession,and getting following response:

```
    { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 77;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Tue, 26 Apr 2016 12:39:23 GMT";
    Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.15";
} } (null)
Data = {"result":{"status":"success","msg":"documents saved Successfully."}}
```

I don't want this Response headers . Using above response unable to parse data.
How can I do this? Please help me.Thanks

Comment: What response? How do you log it? That's the headers data inside de connection from the server, not yours. What

Comment: This is not data this is server side error
Please check the content type that you post with your request,  
is it implemented on server side or not

Comment: check your request and response serialization. check your url in postman or advance rest client from google chrome. check which format data accepts by server and which will be the format of response (for exa : string, json object etc). you can ask your service side person about this

Answer (score 0):

This is not the data as you want.
Please check your request and content type (Mostly), Cos this is server side error when our request is not generated properly or our headers value not satisfy the server side headers value.

And When you get your response data pic it like this

```
 NSString *status = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"result"]valueForKey:@"status"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you dumped the contents of either an NSURLResponse or an NSCachedURLResponse object instead of the actual NSData object that contains the data from the request.  Without seeing your code, I can't say how to fix it, but it seems very clear to me that you're dumping out the contents of the wrong object here.  :-)